Calling native Swift function from Kotlin Multiplatform shared code
I'm trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging on a Kotlin Multiplatform project. Everything is going great except for the iOS part.
I have some shared code:
expect suspend fun getFCMToken(): String?;

And in the Android project, I use actual for a proper implementation and it works. For the iOS code, inside of iosApp, I set up everything correctly, I added this following implementation:
@objc static func getFCMToken() -> String? {
   return Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
}

However, I have been trying to get the shared code to work and call the native Swift code with no luck.
I've tried putting the function in a class and calling that class inside of iosMain kotlin code. I've tried Bridging Header. Both with no luck.

Did you find a solution for this?

I'm going to save you three weeks of slamming your head against the wall like I did.
https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk
If you need one of the uncovered functions in GitLive's Firebase Cloud Messaging API (which 90% are uncovered), I would just reference how they instantiate the Cloud Messaging library.

Hello. Thanks for the library but it doesn't answer the question. I will need this in future features, not just Firebase. Very helpful repo tho, thanks.
